# How to put array values to specific column in listview in C#?

Tags: c#, listview

I created a two listview column '**Sample**' and '**Quantity**' in the design view mode. Now I want to add array data to **mysample to 'Sample'** column and **myquantity to 'Quantity'** column. But I am not how to specific which column the data the should go to. Please help. Here is my code -

```
str[] mysample = somedata;
str[] myquantity = somedata;

for (int i = 0,  i < mysample; i++)
    {
      ListViewItems item1 = new ListViewItem();
      item1.Subitems.Add(mysample[i].ToString());
      listview1.Items.add(item1);

      ListViewItems item2 = new ListViewItem();
      item1.Subitems.Add(myquantity[i].ToString());
      listview1.Items.add(item2);

     }
```

Comment: Generally you add each subsequent (after the first) column of a `ListView` object (`ListViewItem`) as a subitem *of the original* `ListViewItem`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only one `ListViewItem` per row.

```
string[] mysample = { "Sample A", "Sample B", "Sample C"};
string[] myquantity = { "1", "2", "3"};

for (int i = 0; i < mysample.Length; i++)
{
    string[] subitems = new string[] { mysample[i], myquantity[i] };
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(subitems);
    listView1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Also note that to display columns, you should set the `View` to `Details`.

[image: ListBox View property set to Details]

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure the List View's View property is set to Details otherwise the columns wont show up.

You can either do it in the properties window or programmatically

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
```

Then you can add data to multiple columns by passing them to one of `ListViewItem` Class' Initializer Overloads as an Array (with desired sequence) and add it to Your ListView's Items

```
listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] {"column 1" , "column 2", ... }));
```

BTW your code will look like something Like This :

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
            String[] mySample =
            {
                "item 1",
                "item 2",
                "item 3"
            };
            String[] myQuantity =
            {
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            };
            for (var i = 0; i < mySample.Count(); i++)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(new[] {mySample[i],myQuantity[i]}));
            }
```

also a piece of advise , Stop using WindowsForms and Learn WPF instead ;)